# How to extract a function variable value and initialize it to another variable in a different function?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, func

These are my two function and i want to transform the information from function to the other without need to declare a variable to store the information because always when i start my app the initial variable is the one that show up

```
    func action(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.mapView)
    var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)
    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta:latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)
    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = ""        
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation, completionHandler: { (placeMarks, error) -> Void in

     if error != nil 
     {
         println("error: \(error)")
     }
      else {
         let place = CLPlacemark(placemark: placeMarks?[0] as! CLPlacemark)
            }
     })

}
```

Comment: I'm confused with what you're trying to pass? the mapView?

Comment: Why couldn't you use a variable again? Even if you make a function return an object, and immediately pass that object to another function, you're doing the same as creating a variable.

Comment: am trying to pass  the country and subAdministrativeArea and then save it in another view in a tableView i wish that i make it clear...